# I am studying fastapi . I wrotte sample schema in Congig class. but I cannot see a schema in swagger UI

Tags: python, fastapi

api.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from todo import todo_router

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def welcome() -> dict:
    return {
        "message": "Hello World"
    }


app.include_router(todo_router)
```

model.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Todo(BaseModel):
    id: int
    item: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "id": 1,
                "item": "Example Schema!"
            }
        }


class TodoItem(BaseModel):
    item: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "item": "Read the next chapter of the book"
            }
        }
```

todo.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Path
from model import Todo, TodoItem

todo_router = APIRouter()

todo_list = []


@todo_router.post("/todo")
async def add_todo(todo: Todo) -> dict:
    todo_list.append(todo)
    return {
        "message": "Todo added successfully."
    }


@todo_router.get("/todo")
async def retrieve_todos() -> dict:
    return {
        "todos": todo_list
    }


@todo_router.get("/todo/{todo_id}")
async def get_single_todo(todo_id: int) -> dict:
    for todo in todo_list:
        if todo.id == todo_id:
            return {
                "todo": todo
            }
    return {
        "message": "Todo with supplied ID doesn't exist."
    }


@todo_router.put("/todo/{todo_id}")
async def update_todo(todo_data: TodoItem, todo_id: int = Path(..., title="The ID of the todo to be updated.")) -> dict:
    for todo in todo_list:
        if todo.id == todo_id:
            todo.item = todo_data.item
            return {
                "message": "Todo updated successfully."
            }
    return {
        "message": "Todo with supplied ID doesn't exist."
    }


@todo_router.delete("/todo/{todo_id}")
async def delete_single_todo(todo_id: int) -> dict:
    for index in range(len(todo_list)):
        todo = todo_list[index]
        if todo.id == todo_id:
            todo_list.pop(index)
            return {
                "message": "Todo deleted successfully."
            }
    return {
        "message": "Todo with supplied ID doesn't exist."
    }


@todo_router.delete("/todo")
async def delete_all_todo() -> dict:
    todo_list.clear()
    return {
        "message": "Todos deleted successfully."
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joXcz.png)

I want to see a schema in model.py that I wrote. please help me !
This is my first time to study fastapi so It is so hard for me!
I really need help... I dont know the reason why I cannot see a schema.
Tommorow I have a final test using fastapi, gradio, tensorflow etc...
It's been a few months since I've studied coding so , I can not understand everything easliy.

Comment: Pydantic 2 no longer uses `class Config` as its innerclass. Instead you create a `model_config` attribute form the `ConfigDict` class and set the values there. It has also replaced the `schema_extra` key with `json_schema_extra`: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.json_schema_extra

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
todo_router = APIRouter()
```

to

```
todo_router = APIRouter(tags=["My Tag"])
```

Comment: Could you tell me the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find a schema....still

Comment: Please see the FastApi documentation https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/apirouter/ and https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-operation-configuration/

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**